# MATLAB: How can I quickly perform the same set of basic operations on each matrix in an array of matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a 3D array `A` that represents an array of 2D matrices such that `A(i,j,k)` is the `i`th row and the `j`th column of the `k`th matrix.

A process must be performed on each 2D matrix. This process may comprise indexing, addition, subtraction, and elementwise and matrix multiplication and inversion.

The result is stored in another 3D array `B` that represents an array of 2D matrices such that `B(p,q,k)` is the `p`th row and the `q`th column of the `k`th matrix.

To process each matrix I could use a for loop:

```matlab
% Create 4 2x3 matrices with random integers from 1 to 10
A = randi(10, 2, 3, 4); 
% Create a placeholder for the result
B = zeros([2,3,4]);

% For each matrix
for k=1:size(A,3)
    % Isolate the matrix
    a = A(:,:,k);
    % Perform a series of basic matrix operations on it. 
    % Can be limited by combinations of
    % * addition
    % * subtraction
    % * matrix and element-wise multiplication
    % * matrix and element-wise division
    % * indexing
    b = ...
    % Store the result into B
    B(:,:,k) = b;
end
```

However, this can be incredibly time consuming as k becomes large.

How can these matrices be processed more efficiently?

Comment: It's not going to get more efficient that this, unless you can be very specific about which operation you're applying to each matrix.

Comment: The answer may vary depending on exactly which operation you wish to perform. It will also depend on if you you expect to store the result in place or in an additional ND-array.

Comment: Algorithms for time efficiency depend heavily on the operations being done, but MATLAB does make it easy to parallelize using parfor(). perhaps creating a worker for each matrix could yield a faster runtime, but it still may depend on your operations.

Comment: Noted, the question has been clarified

Comment: You’re still not specifying which operations exactly you’re applying. Vectorization depends on the exact sequence of operations applied, there is no magical bullet. For any sufficiently complex sequence of operations inside the loop, the loop will be the most efficient method.

Comment: These are called "page" operations in MATLAB parlance. Many operations in MATLAB are already multi-threaded for these page operations without needing explicit loops.  Element-wise operations: +, -, .*, ./, .^, |, &. And 2D matrix operations: pageinv, pageeig, pagesvd, pagefun, pagenorm, pagemtimes, pagemldivide, pagemrdivide, pagetranspose, pagectranspose. All of these element-wise and 2D matrix page operations operate directly on the variable without requiring temporary page copies such as your A(:,:,k) above in the loop. Just be sure the pages are in the first two dimensions.